# Is it possible to retrieve/build branches tree using github API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I want to visualise my branches using tree structure using github API (similar to network graph on github).

I have not found anything related to it in docs, except retrieving refs. But I don't know how to build branches tree using refs.

Can someone give me some directions?

Comment: What do you mean when asking: __But I don't know how to build branches tree using refs__

Comment: As i understood from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References it's possible to build tree structure using refs. But i can't find any information how. Or may be i just misunderstood this page

Answer (score 0):

> I want to visualise my branches using tree structure

you can do it with a simple git log command

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

Comment: I have only github API. No ability to clone repo